Is there any way to enable Sharable Links using Vercel REST API?
I have built a website builder and I am deploying using Vercel's REST APIs. I want to give users the option to view their website in staging/preview mode.
But on Vercel, by default, deployment protection is enabled, due to which, if users build a website through my app, they will not be able to view the preview deployment, as the API key is of my account.
I see option to do Sharable Links on preview deployments from Vercel Interface. Is there a way to do the same using Vercel REST API?
Docs for reference: https://vercel.com/docs/security/deployment-protection
I have checked a lot of endpoints in their API Docs but haven't been able to find any property to edit this.
